# Scrollbar in text widget appears only at the bottom

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to make a notepad, and I've managed to create something more or less alike, but when I create the scrollbar I only can make it appear at the bottom and don't know how to fix it to the right like a normal scrollbar. here's the code:

```
class Notepad:
    scrollbar = Scrollbar(root)
    Texto = Text(root,wrap=WORD, width=40, height=10,yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
    Texto.grid(sticky= N + S + W + E)
    root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    root.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)

    scrollbar.grid(sticky=E)
    scrollbar.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=0)
    scrollbar.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=0)
    scrollbar.config(command=Texto.yview)
    file = None
```

Answer (score 0):

Right after posting this I came to a solution. Added row=0 and column=1 to the  `scrollbar.grid(sticky=E)` line and also changed the sticky E to N + S.